# Get target url in layout before observer

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer, redirect

I'm inside an observer

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="add_robot" instance="FranceTombale\Robot\Observer\NoindexfollowOnProduct" />
</event>
```

My goal is to alter the layout of some specific url

So inside the observer this is what I have :

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

$redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
$logger->info('Redirect url observer :'.$redirectUrl);
$linkCollection =$this->linkNoIndexCollection->getItems();
foreach ($linkCollection as $item) {
    $urlItem = $item->getData('url');
    if ($urlItem == $redirectUrl) { // .... the code logic updating the layout }
}
```

But this is not acting like I would like it act.

For example, if i'm on the page `htpp://website/home` and I try to go on the page `http://website/myproduct` then the value of `$redirectUrl` is `htpp://website/home` when what I would need for my logic to work is to get the value `http://website/myproduct`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I may did not get you'r problem properly but can you write this observer:

> controller_action_predispatch_

And You can write logic accordingly this:

> $this->*eventManager->dispatch('controller_action_predispatch*' .
> $request->getRouteName(), $eventParameters);